# OpenCV VideoCapture read method returns the same frame

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have written a function that gets a frame from a camera. The first time, it works fine and grabs the frame from the camera, but the next time i call the function it grabs the exact same frame from the first call. I have to call the function 13 times until it finally grabs a new frame from the camera.(for the first call i have an object under the camera, but when i take the object away from the camera and call the function to grab a frame it returns the previous frame with the object in it.)

```
void CamController::setCameras()
{
    qDebug() << "---" << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    //camera serials
    string serials[] = {"11124787", "11124789", "11124782", "11124783", "11124784", "11124785"};
    string pipeline;

    int size = sizeof(serials)/sizeof(serials[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {

        pipeline = "tcambin serial=" + serials[i] + " ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx, 
        width=640, height=480, framerate=50/1 ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false";

        VideoCapture cap;
        cap.open(pipeline);
        _captures.push_back(cap);
    }

}

void CamController::extractFrame()
{
    CamController::setCameras();

    // read frame from camera
    _frameLocker.lock();

    for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(_captures.size()); ++i) {

        Mat _frame;
        bool flag = _captures[i].isOpened();

        if(flag){
            _captures[i].read(_frame);
        }
        else{
            _frame = Mat(800,800, CV_64F, Scalar(0.));
        }

        _frames.push_back(_frame);
    }

    _frameLocker.unlock();
}
```

Comment: the camera captures images continuously and has a buffer included, so if you .read only once then the buffer will be filled and when you .read another later time you will see the first image from that buffer. You can try to reduce the opencv buffer sizes (see parameters of VideoCapture.set) or (which I would recommend) .read all the time and once you need a fresh image, take the last one or the next one that you will read.
You could also destroy the VideoCapture element and create a new one for every new image, but might introduce a bigger latency because of initialization time.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation. I don't really want to destroy videcapture and set it everytime. i think your second solution is the way to go for me.